# How Hide Modal from page source

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, popup

I found this website when I go there a modal pops up but when I click view page source I cant find anything there.

Does anyone know how I can do that? I mean how can I hide my modal from page source?

[here is example](https://4.viki.ge/sazogadoeba/page,2,1180--.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this. Every visible part of a website is somewhere in some part of its source; you must have overlooked it.